# go get doesn't work with .gitconfig that references a custom gitconfig

Tags: git, git-config, go-get

I clone a repository with `git clone` which has a dependency from another private repo. Inside current repo I try to `go get` that dependency (`go get -u ./...`) and it throws me an error:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': terminal
> prompts disabled

### Info

- I used `git clone git@my-name.bitbucket.org:company/repo.git` to clone the repo to `~/Desktop/BitBucket/Company` directory.
- I have `GOPRIVATE="bitbucket.org/company/*"`
- Everything works without `includeIf`. If I replace **.gitconfig** with **company .gitconfig** it works fine. But I need to manage multiple accounts...
- The command `git config --get user.name` (inside the repo) returns `My Name`. So there is a problem with `go get`

My **main .gitconfig** file (in $HOME directory):

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Desktop/BitBucket/Company/"]
        path = ~/.git/BitBucket/Company/.gitconfig
```

My **.gitconfig** file (for company repo $HOME/.git/BitBucket/Company/.gitconfig):

```
[user]
        name = My Name
        email = my.name@company.com
[url "git@my-name.bitbucket.org:"]
        insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

My **ssh config** file ($HOME/.ssh/config):

```
Host my-name.bitbucket.org
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/BitBucket/my_name/id_rsa
```

### What is my mistake?

I also found this article: https://medium.com/easyread/today-i-learned-fix-go-get-private-repository-return-error-terminal-prompts-disabled-8c5549d89045. You can check the first comment:

> FYI, this dont work when using .gitconfig that references a custom
> .gitconfig-custom. It has to live in ~/.gitconfig….. man that was
> frustrating.

I tried to move **company .gitconfig** to home directory (+ renamed it .gitconfig-company). Nothing works.

Comment: You would like to use your pro account only for `bitbucket.org/company/*` urls, right ? Have you tried to rewrite only `https://bitbucket.org/company/` urls ? with `git@my-name.bitbucket.org:company/` ? (note : I haven't tested it, not sure this rewting rule works)

Comment: One way to test your setup is : run `git clone https://bitbucket.org/company/repo`, and see if it prompts for a password. You may turn on options to have a more verbose output : `git clone -v ...`, `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone ...`, ...

Comment: @LeGEC I have tried to rewrite url that way, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with go1.17 installed by snap with some one my machine. If I download and set variables manually all work fine. I thing go get us some another .gitconfig file

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `go get` to clone a repository, be aware that the `gitdir:` and `gitdir/i:` patterns don't match a repository that's being cloned.  That's because the pattern matches directories that are `.git` directories, and when you're cloning, that `.git` directory hasn't been created yet.

You could try placing a directive like this into your config instead:

```
[url "git@my-name.bitbucket.org:company/"]
        insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/company/
```

and then setting up a non-work key for Bitbucket if you need to clone other (public) repositories.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I clone repository with ```git clone``` and inside this repo I have a dependency which I try to ```go get```. I have tried your solution but unfortunately I see the same error.

Comment: "patterns don't match a repository that's being cloned" seems like a pretty big oversight since cloning is a great example of a time when using personal/business credentials is important.